# How to Remove Ghost Duplicate Pins in Circuit Appearance

Tags: logisim

One of my subcircuits I designed for some reason has more pins in the circuit appearance than it has in the circuit itself. In the actual subcircuit, there are 47 pins, which is the correct amount. I took the picture while moving all the pins to show that none are unselected [image: subcircuit shows 47 pins]

Now when I go to modify the circuit appearance, it shows that I have 51 pins. 4 more than I actually have.
[image: subcircuit appearance shows 51 pins]
Some of my pins are for some reason duplicated. At least I assume so. I found 2 pins that are leading to almost the same exact spot. One leads to the actual pin:[image: blue outline around where the pin actually is], and one that leads to where the pin used to be located a while ago: [image]

This is the view from inside the circuit: [image: View of inside of subcircuit] As you can tell, there isn't a pin where it says there is. And when I'm using the subcircuit, either both of them have the same label, or neither of them have a label. Putting an input onto the pins does nothing. The pins are progressively duplicating. At one point, I only had one duplicate. Now, I have 4. I have no idea what's creating these, where they're leading to, or how to delete them. I could likely use the circuit just find by storing them all in one spot that won't be used, but I'd rather just delete them. How can I get rid of these, or am I going to have to just have them exist?

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce this behavior? Or place an example file at some publically accessible location?

Comment: @thebusybee I have no idea what causes it. I just uploaded the file to [here](https://github.com/SudoWatson/Misc/blob/main/brokenquestionmark.circ). It runs on Logisim Evolution 2.13.8. The "Register_Controller" circuit is the one with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have Logisim Evolution installed, but the last "original" Logisim, version 2.7.1. Opening the circuit led to an error message concerning 4 erroneous elements "circ-port".

Anyway, the saved circuit is an XML file. And you can open it with any editor, but using a programmer's editor highlights the syntax, which is really helpful.

So I did, and looked in the circuit "Register_Controller". Matching the list of "circuit-ports" of the "appearance" (lines 2837 to 2888) with the pins (lines 3031 to 3369) revealed that four of the circuit-ports have no pins in the circuit.

Deleting the lines 2846, 2848, 2850, and 2852 (and saving the file with a new name) made Logisim load the file without error message.

Here are the lines (with the not-to-be-deleted lines between them):

```xml
      <circ-port height="10" pin="190,330" width="10" x="75" y="75"/>   <!-- delete me -->
      <circ-port height="8" pin="280,370" width="8" x="46" y="136"/>
      <circ-port height="8" pin="190,380" width="8" x="46" y="156"/>   <!-- delete me -->
      <circ-port height="10" pin="530,390" width="10" x="45" y="185"/>
      <circ-port height="10" pin="190,400" width="10" x="75" y="65"/>   <!-- delete me -->
      <circ-port height="10" pin="530,410" width="10" x="45" y="195"/>
      <circ-port height="10" pin="190,420" width="10" x="65" y="455"/>   <!-- delete me -->
```

After sorting the coordinates, I also found duplicates at the coordinates (200,330), (200,380), and (200,400). These are named `NOT`(`NOT`), `Out` (`ROut`), and `Load` (`RIn`), respectively.

However, I have no idea ***why*** Logisim Evolution produced this erroneous circuit. Presumably there is a bug in it. You might consider to report this at the project's site.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I never thought to look into the file itself. I deleted those lines and it's working again. The other duplicates you mentioned are fine, as they're connected just without a wire, but thanks for the worry on them. And I would report it, however I know I have an older version because I haven't been able to get a newer version running for some reason.